# Proving directional derivative identities

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

my math professor just taught me directional derivatives and some of their identities, however he did not show us the proof to these identities. After a thorough comb through many textbooks and the internet, I am unable to find satisfactory proof of them, hence could I have some help in proving these? Thank you!
$$D_v(f\pm g)=D_vf\pm D_vg$$
$$D_v(cf)=cD_v(f)$$
Finally, Leibniz's rule: $D_v(fg)=gD_vf+fD_vg$

Comment: Your definition of directional derivative is? You must have attempted these from the first principles governed by the definition. If you have not made an attempt, then just mention the definition first.

Comment: As far, I only know that $D_f = \nabla f \cdot v \vec$ where $v \vec$ is a vector in the input space which can have any arbitrary direction. The direction of $v \vec$ will influence the output in different ways and the maximum of the directional derivative is the gradient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of a directional derivative is as follows:

> Let $U \subset \Bbb{R}^n$ be open, let $v \in \Bbb{R}^n$, $x \in U$, and let $f:U \to \Bbb{R}$ be a function. We say $f$ has a directional derivative at the point $x$ along the vector $v$ (in the "direction" $v$), if the limit
> \begin{align}
> \lim_{t \to 0}\dfrac{f(x+tv) - f(x)}{t}
> \end{align}
> exists. In this case, we denote the limit as $(D_vf)(x)$, or just $D_vf(x)$.

Now, notice that this limit can also be equivalently expressed as follows: we define the function $\gamma: I\subset \Bbb{R} \to U$ ($I$ being a small open interval containing $0$) as $\gamma(t) = x+tv$. Then, the limit in question is exactly the same as $(f\circ \gamma)'(0)$ (just write out what this means using the standard single variable definition of differentiability).

Now, the things you want to prove are simple consequences of the relevant facts from single-variable calculus. For example, I'll do the "hardest" one regarding the product rule, and leave the simpler ones of linearity to you. Now, our assumption is that $D_vf(x)$ and $D_vg(x)$ exist; and we want to prove that $D_v(fg)(x)$ also exists and equals
\begin{align}
D_v(fg)(x) &= f(x)\cdot [D_vg(x)] + [D_vf(x)]\cdot g(x)
\end{align}
This is very simple, because like I mentioned above, taking a directional derivative means you compose the function with $\gamma(t) = x+tv$, and then take the derivative at $t=0$. Now,
\begin{align}
[(f\cdot g)\circ \gamma](t) = (f\cdot g)(\gamma(t)) = f(\gamma(t)) \cdot g(\gamma(t)) = [f \circ \gamma](t) \cdot [g\circ \gamma](t)
\end{align}
In other words, $(f\cdot g)\circ \gamma = (f \circ \gamma)\cdot (g\circ \gamma)$. So, we have
\begin{align}
D_v(f\cdot g)(x) &= [(f \cdot g)\circ \gamma]'(0) \\
&= [(f \circ \gamma)\cdot (g \circ \gamma)]'(0) \\
&= (f\circ \gamma)(0) \cdot (g \circ \gamma)'(0) + (f \circ \gamma)'(0)\cdot (g \circ \gamma)(0) \\
&= f(x) \cdot [D_vg(x)] + [D_vf(x)] \cdot g(x),
\end{align}
where in the third equal sign, I used the product rule which you probably know from single variable calculus. I leave it to you to write out the proof for the linearity of directional derivatives.

Answer (score 0):

For a differentiable function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$ the directional derivative of $f$ in the direction $v = (v_1, \dots, v_n)$ can be written

$$ D_v(f) = \sum_{i=1}^nv_i\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}$$

All the properties you list then follow immediately from the properties of partial derivatives.

**Edit:** It has been pointed out that $f$ doesn't need to be differentiable for directional derivatives to exist. So this answer only applies for functions that are differentiable, and therefore doesn't fully answer your question.

Comment: The equality involving $D_v(f)$ is not necessarily true if $f$ isn't differentiable !

Comment: @Digitallissimo Isn't the differentiability of $f$ necessary for the directional derivative to be defined in the first place? **Edit**: Just found an example where it doesn't have to be differentiable but directional derivatives exist. Learn something new everyday!

Comment: Your answer is "close" though, in the sense that the various properties of directional derivatives reduce almost directly to the relevant facts from single variable calculus (see my answer). So you had the right idea, but not quite the right execution.