# Why is $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} \Big|_p = (f\circ \alpha)'(0)$ true?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

In my multivariable calculus class notes my teacher wrote the following:

> Let $p = (x_1^0, ... , x_n^0)$ and $\alpha: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R^n$ such that $\alpha(x) = (x_1^0,...,x_{i-1}^0, x, x_{i+1}^0, ..., x_n^0)$, and $f:\mathbb R^n \to \Bbb R$. Then:
> $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} \Big|_p = (f\circ \alpha)'(0)\ \ \ \ (1)$$
> And because of this, we can conclude that partial derivatives follow the same rules as regular derivatives.

My questions are:

1 - Why is $(1)$ true? Shouldn't it be:

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} \Big|_p = (f\circ \alpha)'(x_i^0)$$

instead?

2 - How can we conclude that partial derivatives follow the same rules as regular derivatives from this equality?

Comment: For (1), you are correct and that should be a typo. For (2), not sure what you are asking...

Comment: For (2), because $(f+g)\circ \alpha = (f\circ \alpha)+(g\circ \alpha)$ and $(f\cdot g)\circ \alpha=(f\circ \alpha)\cdot (g\circ \alpha)$, so the sum rules and product rules for partial derivatives follow from the single-variable case. See [proving directional derivative identities](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3747292/568204) for more details.

Comment: As an aside on (1), it is quite common to define functions like $\alpha$ as $\alpha(t) = x_i^0 + t$ instead of the way it was. Had this been done, then $(f\circ \alpha)'(0)$ would have been correct. Probably the author overlooked that they were mixing up common approaches.